# Can I still deduct contributions to my Traditional IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira, contribution

I worked as a consultant on W2 from January 2012 until October 2012. My company did not offer any 401k. In November 2012, I got a full time job and the new company offered a 401K and enrolled me in the plan.

Since I was not offered any 401k for most of the year, I maxed out my Traditional IRA before joining the new company.

The company that I joined in November 2012 put the default 2% in my 401k which came in my W2 as $300.

My question is: Can I still deduct my Traditional IRA contribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

For 2012 the phaseout range for deducting an IRA contribution when you are covered by a retirement plan at work are as follows:

- For single filers: $58,000 to $68,000
- For head of household filers: $58,000 to $68,000
- For married couples filing jointly: $92,000 to $112,000
- For married couples filing separately: $0 to $10,000

Unfortunately, 'covered' isn't qualified by any minimum time.

Comment: Its not qualified by any minimum because you can technically deposit the whole $17000 in your 401k in one lump sum, as long as you earned as much. But the OP can either withdraw the excess IRA contribution, or leave it as non-deductible, or convert to ROTH.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Are you referring to gross income or net income?

Comment: The IRA phaseout number are Adjusted Gross Income

Comment: Thanks. I did some research and i think i either have to move the excess contribution either to ROTH ira or withdraw it. I probably withdraw it and put it towards my car loan.

Comment: @Asdfg: I would recommend that you recharacterize it to a Roth IRA.

Comment: _Making_ a contribution to a Roth IRA is also not permitted for high-income earners (though the limits are higher). Pub 590 says "Generally, you can contribute to a Roth IRA if you have taxable compensation ... and your modified AGI ... is less than (i) $183,000 for married filing jointly or qualifying widow(er), (ii) $125,000 for single, head of household, or married filing separately and you did not live with your spouse at any time during the year, (iii)
$10,000 for married filing separately and you lived
with your spouse at any time during the year. So check before re-characterizing.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Right. If the OP doesn't qualify to contribute to a Roth IRA, he should instead convert it to a Roth IRA. (this is the "backdoor Roth IRA")

Comment: @user102008 Errr not quite. If the OP does not qualify to contribute to a Roth IRA because the MAGI is too high, he does not qualify to make a deductible Traditional IRA contribution either because the Roth MAGI limitation kicks in at a higher level. So, the contribution already made would need to be recharacterized as a nondeductible Traditional IRA contribution and _then_ converted to a Roth IRA, but this brings up issues of whether he has other Traditional IRA accounts whose value will affect how much gets converted to a Roth IRA and how much is taxable etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: there's no such thing as "recharacterized as a nondeductible Traditional IRA contribution". A nondeductible Traditional IRA contribution is simply a Traditional IRA contribution that you choose not to deduct. (He couldn't deduct it anyway, or we wouldn't be having this discussion; so it's automatically nondeductible.) Yes, there would be issues if he has other deductable Traditional IRA money.

Comment: Well, the OP does need to file Form 8606 along with Form 1040 to declare that money as a nondeductible contribution to his Traditional IRA, because the custodian _is_ going to report an IRA contribution for 2012 on Form 5498.